# Hadoop: compare 2 different file systems

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i want to compare 2 file systems. One has few Data and the other has much more. I decide to do that with HDFS and i've already download both on the HDFS.

After some research, i found out i can use CacheFile in my map reduce routine, which i did. Now i don't know the best way to manage the data file and iterate over both.

Just need some ideas to implements it correctly and with good performance.

Hier is map code:

```
public static class DataPreparationMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private URI file;
        @Override
        protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            this.file = context.getCacheFiles()[0];
//          super.setup(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                context.write(new Text(this.file.toString()), new Text("File found!")); // Station-Datum als Key und Value = 1
//          super.map(key, value, context);
        }
    }
```

Notice: the output, it was to check if i can read the path where my cache data are. So the code doesn't do anything productive yet.

Comment: You want to compare 2 files in HDFS or 2 different file systems? For e.g HDFS vs S3 file system?

Comment: i'm trying to solve a problem where i need to computed frequencies of words occurring in a file1 from file2.

Comment: How can i read from 2 different HDFS?